# Как исправить ошибку No cached version of com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5 available for offline mode.?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Обновил постгрес, грейдл и жуук до последних версий и при запуске gradle flywayClean стала возникать ошибка:

Execution failed for task ':clg:flywayClean'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':clg:compile'.
>   Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5.
>        Required by:
>            project :clg
>   No cached version of com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5 available for offline mode.
>   Could not resolve com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.16.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :clg
>   No cached version of com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.16.0 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.16.0 available for offline mode.

Comment: выключить оффлайн режим в настройках студии наверное

Comment: он выключен 4 символа